# How to erase HTML5 appcache from user browser to move from http to https?

Tags: http, https, html5-appcache

I have a site with that runs with http and HTML5 appcache. Now I want to use https. I have all setup but the cache will fail to fetch with https now because it tries to fetch the http version.

So if I deploy now the users won't be able to use the new version. What can I do?

**Edit 1**: It seems that if I remove the appcache manifest from the server and then wait to the users get a version without appcache I can update to https and it will work. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, mistakenly, though it is Apache. However, I have rolled it back.

Comment: It's ok, I just changed the question and included "HTML5" to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I used this javascript workaround:

```
if (location != null && location.protocol == 'http:') 
location.href = location.href.replace('http://', 'https://');
```

So just order the browser to go to the https version.
I removes the manifest from the http version and will keep the http version live for some time.